# ng-multiselect-dropdown how to programmatically deselect

Tags: angular, ng-multiselect-dropdown

I have a dropdown that affects a second dependant dropdown. When the first is in a state of nothing selected, I want the dependant dropdown to also have whatever is selected deselected. Therefore I need to programmatically deselect the second dropdown.

I've got as far as resetting the selectedItems array to [] which clears the dropdown list. However, the previously selected items are still sitting in the bar where the placeholder text should ideally be restored. How can I do this?

Comment: Without code sample is not possible for anyone to gives you a proper solution,

Comment: I understand your point however this question does not regard a specific problem within my code but rather a general question regarding a plugin. I could phrase the whole question as this: how can one programmatically deselect items and have the bar that shows selected items reflect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by resetting the form.

In my HTML component I gave it a form name: `formControlName="multiselect"`

In my typescript I had this `@ViewChild('multiselect') multiSelect;` and a method which did this: `this.form.get("multiselect").setValue([]);` and called it whenever I deselected in the first multiselect or selected a new option in the first multiselect.

Worked a treat!